# Which way should be preferred over while creating generic arraylist?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, collections

I was reading about Generics. And got into a situation:

```
List<Object> t1 = new ArrayList<>();

or 

List<?> t2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

What is the difference in this 2 statements? Which one should be preferred?

Comment: now create a list of Strings and try assigning it to t1 and t2.

Comment: What's the point of using generics in this case? Might as well just write `List t = new ArrayList();`.

Comment: Try adding an element to `t2`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen That's awful advice.

Comment: @shmosel It gives error `The method add(capture#1-of ?) in the type List<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (String)`

Comment: @shmosel If that's the case, then why they mention about unbounded wildcards?? How can i use unbounded wildcards?

Comment: @shmosel I agree. Better advice would be: don't create heterogeneous lists.

Comment: `System.out::println`? This is java.

Comment: @mackycheese21 Yes... yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

In `List<Object> t1=new ArrayList<>();`, you are creating a `List` object with generic type `Object`.  The empty diamond symbol on the right is inferred to be `<Object>`.

On the bottom, with `List<?>t2=new ArrayList<>();`
This gives a compiler error:

`Unexpected token: ?`

This is because the Java compiler cannot infer what the generic type of your `List` is.  If you had not declared it with `t2=new ArrayList<>();` and left the compiler to infer the type, you could have instantiated it with any generic (`t2=new ArrayList<YourObjectTypeHere>()`).

So if you had to pick one, DONT do the second one as that gives a compile error.